# CSS grid - variable layout placement on different screens + background

Tags: css, css-grid

Designer's intentions are to have background color under certain amount of elements on desktop and under another set of elements on mobile.

Grid within grid. The layout for desktop is as shown on the picture and on the Liveweave playground. For mobile, designer wants both "I" block (left bottom) to be below "G" block (right center) and all the elements would have background color instead of just A-H blocks. Because of the background color, I wrapped A-H blocks within another element, so the named blocks are not on the same level.

Actual implementation: https://liveweave.com/jxIgSV

Demo:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 36.66667%;
  gap: 35px;
}

.fieldset {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  grid-template-columns: 24% 40% 7.5% 26%;
  grid-template-areas: "a b e f" "a c e g" "a d . g" ". h . .";
  gap: 6px 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(39px, auto);
}

.f {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  background: red;
}

.f-a {
  grid-area: a;
}

.f-b {
  grid-area: b;
}

.f-c {
  grid-area: c;
}

.f-d {
  grid-area: d;
}

.f-e {
  grid-area: e;
}

.f-f {
  grid-area: f;
}

.f-g {
  grid-area: g;
}

.f-h {
  grid-area: h;
}


/*.f-i { grid-area: i; }
    .f-j { grid-area: j; }*/
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="fieldset">
    <div class="f f-a">A</div>
    <div class="f f-b">B</div>
    <div class="f f-c">C</div>
    <div class="f f-d">D</div>
    <div class="f f-e">E</div>
    <div class="f f-f">F</div>
    <div class="f f-g">G</div>
    <div class="f f-h">H</div>
  </div>
  <div class="f f-i">I</div>
  <div class="f f-j">J</div>
</div>
```

[image: grid within grid]

I cannot think of a way how to provide background color for only subset of grid children. I'm aiming for a clear way, I can think of absolutely positioned pseudoelement underlaying the grid to some extent as a space occupied by its children is somewhat the same.

Comment: So the goal is to have background color to specific items inside this grid, right ?

Comment: exactly - for desktop version, they're wrapped in `.fieldset`, for mobile/tablet they should all have background color + one of the items should be on a different position

Comment: Why don't you wrap them all in one grid,not 2 ..then to change the bgcolor for specific area just (g for example) add : .f-g {background-color: red}

Comment: Then o handle mobiles add queries to your css to override the old properties

Comment: If you can have 2 images for expected result in mobile and desktop I can help you with it.

Comment: with background-coloring of specific area, I'd lose posibility of gap property usage - but that could be replaced by padding/margin for area blocks. so far the best idea

Comment: No you won't lose gap usage, just test it with simple grid of 2-3 areas , you'll notice that the gap will remain

Comment: gap will remain, but as you can see in the code snippet, background is not underlaying the whole upper part of the form (`.fieldset {
  background-color: #f8f8f8;... }`) as intended by design (I was not probably clear in the original question, sry)